# switch statment in echo

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

How can use CASE SWITCH PHP exactly. I have in function.php the code without case switch, and the page not see database, css, javascript.... I want use the link with switch, I have correctly id in the link, but the link is not work.

This is the code in this moment

```
echo "<td>{$company}<br><a href='admin/includes/profile.php?case_id={$customer_id}'>View </a>
```

but I want use like this

```
echo "<td>{$company}<br><a href='customer.php?customer=edit_customer?case_id={$customer_id}'>View </a>
```

I used in customer.php

```
  case 'edit_customer';
  include "admin/includes/profile.php";
  break;
```

And in profile.php

```
if(isset($_GET['case_id'])){
$customer_id = $_GET['case_id'];
}
```

So. The link is there and is good (is take correctly id from database) but the link is not work.

Comment: Have you check in google dev which link is output in html?

Comment: Only one `?` in parameters please: change `?customer=edit_customer?case_id={$customer_id}` to `?customer=edit_customer&case_id={$customer_id}`

Comment: Ok. I understand now. Thank you for answer.

Comment: _“How can use CASE SWITCH PHP exactly”_ - wrong question. Correct question would be, how can I analyze problems _properly_, so that I don’t go looking into completely the wrong direction. A simple debug output of the content of $_GET would have shown you here, where things are _actually_ going wrong.

Comment: `<?php print_r($_GET) ?>` would have solved your problem.